# now when I got older

Tags: past-simple

I saw this sentence in my English training course. I don't understand how it's possible to combine "now" and Past Simple. Is there a mistake in the sentence or not? Could you explain, please? How is this sentence said idiomatically?

> I didn’t use to understand my parents, but **now when I got older** I do.

Comment: Try looking up the word "now" in a dictionary. Anyway, that is terrible English. It should be: now that I am older. But, hey, there's nothing to be done about Russians writing English textbooks.

Comment: "I used not to understand my parents, but [now I have got older]/[now that I am older], I do."

Comment: Personally I think *didn't **used** to [do something]* seems "more correct", but apparently [*that's not what we **used** to say.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=didn%E2%80%99t+use+to+understand%2Cdidn%E2%80%99t+used+to+understand&year_start=1840&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10)

Comment: Ask for a refund